# Statistics of Trigger impact on performance

Tags: sql-server

Do we have any medium that we can track or identify, how much percentage trigger impacting performance on particular process.

Is there any system tables or view where we can track?

Comment: SQL SERVER Database

Answer (score 0):

You don't measure the triggers as a % "performance impact".

You should be considering the whole system. You put representative workloads through the system and measure the performance.

Then, if you don't like the performance and you believe the triggers could be the cause, you do another measure where you remove the triggers but the workload includes *whatever you'd do if you don't have the triggers in place to achieve the same aims*<sup>1</sup>. That second measure is *highly specific* to you alone so there's no way to be able to say what a % different between those workloads would be.

---

<sup>1</sup>I.e. what's the point of just measuring triggers/no triggers when "no triggers" presumably doesn't give you something you have a requirement for.

Comment: I have lot of triggers in my database, and running performance issue. Customer was asking for statistics of trigger impact which they can think whether trigger can be remove and achieve business with some other mechanism.

Comment: Yes, but you need a concrete idea of *what you would replace them with* and that's your-db-and-business specific. Once you have an alternative, then you can measure one versus the other and know which one works best.